# SIGTRAP in Core Data iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have this function returning a SIGTRAP in two places.

```
- (void)addShindy:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    AddShindyViewController *addShindyViewController = [[AddShindyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddShindyViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addShindyViewController];

    addShindyViewController.delegate = self;

    NSManagedObjectContext *addingContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [addingContext setParentContext:[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext]];
    // SIGTRAP occurring on line above this

    Shindy *shindy = (Shindy *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Shindy" inManagedObjectContext:addingContext];
    addShindyViewController.shindy = shindy;
    addShindyViewController.managedObjectContext = addingContext;

    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I suspect that the error has to do with the "adding context" because the two lines that throw an error both have that in common.

I can post more code if anybody needs me to.

Comment: More information would be useful, what exactly is there error and which lines is it occurring on?

Comment: The error is a SIGTRAP. The error log is just a main, 0_kill type of error. That means that it gives as close to no information about the crash as possible.

Comment: On what line is it occurring?

Comment: `[addingContext setParentContext:[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext]];`

Comment: SIGTRAP is thrown if there was an uncaught Obj-C exception. If you look at the console (Xcode -> Organizer -> Device -> Console), there should be a log message telling you which exception was thrown as well as some more details provided by the code that threw the exception. You will get the same in the Xcode debugger pane if you run your code from within Xcode on you device (or within the simulator).

Comment: @Mecki Okay, well this is what I got in the console for an iOS device.

`<Debug>: 023214.574464 wlan.A[20235]` `AppleBCMWLANNetManager::checkRealTimeTraffic():  now 23214.574456708 num entries 4`
I'm pretty sure that is useless information...

Comment: Yeah, that appears to be an unrelated system service, can you post the full console output from Xcode's debugger console? Not the device console where you are seeing all of those system logs.

Comment: Where can I access that for the Simulator? I can't find anything... If what I'm thinking is right, and the console is simply displayed at the bottom of the XCode application, then the console doesn't return anything.